# How to change the properties of a service bus queue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azureservicebus

I am using service bus queues to communicate between web role and worker role. Sometimes web role messages are not being accepted by worker role. But it immediately accepts the next message i send. So i was thinking maybe its happening because the Batched Operations is enabled. I have been trying to put it to false but i havent been successful. This is my code.

```
public static QueueClient GetServiceBusQueueClient(string queuename)
    {            
        string connectionString;

        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
         connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        else
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];          


        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

        QueueDescription queue = null;

        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queuename))
        {
            queue = namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queuename);
            queue.EnableBatchedOperations = false;
            queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            queue = namespaceManager.GetQueue(queuename);
            queue.EnableBatchedOperations = false;
            queue.MaxDeliveryCount = 1000;
        }

        MessagingFactorySettings mfs = new MessagingFactorySettings();
        mfs.NetMessagingTransportSettings.BatchFlushInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;

        string issuer;
        string accessKey;
         if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
            issuer = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ISSUER");
         else
             issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ISSUER"];

        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
            accessKey = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY");
        else
            accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY"];

        mfs.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuer, accessKey);
        MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(namespaceManager.Address, mfs);

        QueueClient Client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(queue.Path);            

        return Client;
    }
```

But the EnableBatchedOperations is always true and the MaxDeliveryCount is always 10 by default.

Let me know if you know what's the issue

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the `EnabledBatchedOperations`, you have to do that *before* you create the queue.  you do that by creating a `QueueDescription` object then pass that to the `CreateQueue` method.  For example:

```
QueueDescription orderQueueDescription =
    new QueueDescription(queuename)
    {
        RequiresDuplicateDetection = true,
        MaxDeliveryCount = 1000,
    };
namespaceMgr.CreateQueue(orderQueueDescription);
```

### Update:

The documentation is pretty clear on this:

> Since metadata cannot be changed once a messaging entity is created, modifying the duplicate detection behavior requires deleting and recreating the queue. The same principle applies to any other metadata. [1]

`QueueDescription` *Represents the metadata description of the queue.*

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh532012.aspx

Comment: It's also worth adding that the `UpdateQueue` operation on `NamespaceManager` doesn't let you update this property - you can **only** set it before the queue is created.

Comment: Thank you! I just need help with one more thing. Can u confirm that the way i have set Batch Flush Interval to zero is correct? Because there is no way to see if it has been set to zero. Thanks again

Comment: @Bitsian I'm not sure what you mean by "correct".  Yes, you can set the value to zero without error.  What that does is disable batching.  If that's what you want, then you're doing it correctly.

Comment: Ya i wanted batching to be disabled. But i was setting Batch Flush Interval after the queue was created, thats why i asked if the code i wrote for it would work.

Comment: And any idea what batching does? i am guessing the queue client will wait to gather a few messages to send them as a batch? In my case, the messages are not being received on the first time they are sent. If i send a message again, then the previous message is received this time.

Comment: @Bitsian Ah, okay. No, the `MessageFactorySettings` (with the `NetMessagingTransportSettings`) is a property of a *Factory* which is used to set the settings of a queue when *created*.  As the documentation alludes to, metadata information about queues can only be "set" during creation.

Comment: @Bitsian `BatchFlushInterval` applies to implicit batching.  The system may decide that it will batch some operations because it thinks it will be more efficient (and I assume, still safe).  you can use `BatchFlushInterval` (by setting it to Zero) to ask the system to *never* do that on a newly created queue (or topic, I assume)

Answer (score 1):

**Update Azure SDK 2.3**

UpdateQueue method on the NamespaceManager **still** doesn't let you update any properties apart from suspending or resuming the queue.

If you need to change MaxDeliveryCount on an existing queue and you don't want to delete and recreate the queue, your only option is to change it in the Azure portal.

Comment: How can I change it in the Azure portal? That option is not present in my portal ...

Comment: Check out the screenshot from this tutorial https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/an-introduction-to-windows-azure-service-bus-brokered-messaging/

Comment: I read the page you recommended. Just to try it out I created a new Queue. There is an edit page as you said. BUT In my case I have a topic with a subscription queue. From some reason the portal does not allow you to edit properties of a subscription queue ... Why that locking limitation???